# Generic way to get the path to the terminal binary on different Linux systems?

Tags: linux, terminal

I've got the following hardcoded list of terminals in my application:

```
"/usr/bin/konsole", // KDE
"/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", // Gnome
"/usr/bin/pantheon-terminal" // Pantheon (Elementary OS)
```

I then simply grab the first entry from this list that points to an existing file. Obviously, the problem is that the program stops working as soon as it's run on a system with unknown terminal binary. So, can I determine it in some generic way? Via some standard environment variable, perhaps?

Comment: IMHO it might be useful to explain what is it that your program intents to do with such terminal binary info: launch it? determine if it is the one actually running? etc.

Comment: @DanCornilescu: just launch it in the specified working directory.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd only keep the terminal executable names in the list and dynamically determine their actual paths based on the `PATH` env var - depending on the distribution and/or the installation options they might be in other locations. Or use `which <terminal executable>` which does that for you.

I'd use `xterm` as the final fallback terminal - it's pretty much standard on any X-Windows installation.

Other convenience considerations:

- check if `DISPLAY` is set - if it's not most likely the terminals won't run
- try to determine the actual graphics environment and first try the more appropriate one for it. `WINDOWMANAGER` may help. Specific window managers typically set their own env vars, for example in my case KDE sets: `KDE_SESSION_UID`, `KDE_FULL_SESSION`, `KDE_MULTIHEAD`, `KDE_SESSION_VERSION`.